# how to set the transparency of a matplotlib.image object?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I normally know how to change the transparency of plots in matplotlib.

But this plot I am having trouble to do it

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.image import NonUniformImage
Y = [2, 12, 52]
X = [10, 100]
ymin, ymax = 0, 60
xmin, xmax = 0, 150
Z = np.random.rand(len(Y), len(X))
extent = [xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = NonUniformImage(ax, interpolation='nearest', extent=extent, alpha=0.1)
im.set_data(X, Y, Z)
im.set_clip_path(ax.patch)
ax.images.append(im)
ax.set_xlim(extent[0], extent[1])
ax.set_ylim(extent[2], extent[3])
ax.set_xticks(X)
ax.set_yticks(Y)
```

I try to put `alpha=0.1` in several places, e.g.

`ax.images.append(im, alpha=0.1)`

`im.set_data(X, Y, Z.T, alpha=0.1)`

`im = NonUniformImage(ax, interpolation='nearest', extent=extent, alpha=0.1)`

and none of them work.
I need NonUniformImage because I have unequally spaced bins

Thank you for your help

Comment: There are quite a few issues with `NonUniformImage`. It seems alpha is not implemented, similar to how it isn't for `PcolorImage`, see [issues/13328](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13328). So for the time being, you need to use (the somewhat slower) `pcolormesh`, which supports alpha just fine.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, thanks for the tip. But pcolormesh seems also to have trouble with alpha. check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59664708/how-to-get-rid-of-diagonal-lines-on-pcolormesh-with-option-gouraud